# replace texts that aren't in any tag

Tags: javascript, replace, html

i use this code to get text of all nodes in body (Browser is IE8 it works on FF...)

thanks ,i develop a toolbar to change some texts in pages so if you have any other solution will made me happy,if i replace all of body with regex,it disable some futures of sites.for example in facebook if use replace all suggestion future will disable in friend finds section,so i want to change words step by step,it's a filter for bad words

```
function replaceText(node)
{
 var textPropName = node.textContent === undefined ? 'innerText' : 'textContent';
 var childs = node.childNodes, i = 0;
 while(i < childs.length)    
 {
 alert(childs[i][textPropName]);
   if (childs[i][textPropName] !=null)
    {
      childs[i][textPropName] =childs[i][textPropName].replace(rgx,'new');
    }
    else
    {
      replaceText(document.body.childNodes[i]);} i++; 
    }
 }
}
```

it's work and i can replace all text on a page but if a text be in out of tags same as belove i can't access to it and replace it
**problem:** `test5 ww tt xx` test aren't in any tag so they don't replaced
any solution?
sincerely

```
ww tt ff xx test5 test
<b>
test old old  yyyl  yyy ppp  
  <h2> ppp gfdsgfds gf dg df   yyy old odld old</h2>
</b>
  <h1 id="myHeader" onClick="replaceText(document.body)"> 
     yyy   yyy  yyy  yyy   old Click me! whatever
 </h1>
ppp  ppp ppp bwhoreface 
<b> 
ppp
```

end solution

```
function replaceText(node){ 
var textPropName = node.textContent === undefined ? 'innerText' : 'textContent';
   var childs = node.childNodes, i = 0;
var len= node.childNodes.length;
// alert('len='+len);
//var rgx = new RegExp('\\bold\\b', 'gi');
   while(node = childs[i]){
//alert('ee'+node.nodeType);  
if (node.nodeType == 3  ) {
//alert('!!!!!'+node.nodeValue );
//alert('ee'+node.nodeType); 
childs[i].nodeValue = childs[i].nodeValue.replace(rgx, 'newText'); 
} else { 
   replaceText(node); 

}
```

Comment: How do you call your function `replaceText`?

Comment: i call it from h1 tag onClick="replaceText(document.body)

Comment: What is the value of `rgx`?

Comment: it's not important it's like as var rgx = new RegExp('\\bff\\b|\\byyy\\b', 'gi'); but i check value of child with  'alert(childs[i][textPropName])' and all text that aren't in tags will not show in messagebox,just text that are in tags will be alerted

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, this works in IE too...

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HhRRB/)

```
function replaceText(node)
{
    var textPropName = node.textContent === undefined ? 'innerText' : 'textContent';
    var childs = node.childNodes, i = 0;
    var rgx = new RegExp('\\bff\\b|\\byyy\\b', 'gi');

    while(i < childs.length)    
    {
        if(childs[i].nodeType == 3) {
            alert(childs[i].nodeValue);

            childs[i].nodeValue = childs[i].nodeValue.replace(rgx,'new');
        } else {
            alert(childs[i][textPropName]);

            if (childs[i][textPropName] !=null)
            {
                childs[i][textPropName] =childs[i][textPropName].replace(rgx,'new');
            }
            else
            {
                replaceText(document.body.childNodes[i]);
            } 
        }

        i++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: problem: please visit this url http://bwf.begardin.com/a.html  why after changing sex word page changed and only show texts?

Answer (score 0):

Use **content()** property :- It Gets the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes.

try this:

```
// in jquery
$("body").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).replaceWith("hello");


// in javascript
var nodes = document.getElementsByName('body').childNodes
for (i=0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
 if(nodes.childNode[i].nodeType == 3)
 {
 //THIS NODE IS A TEXT NODE OF THE BODY ELEMENT
 //DO WHAT YOU NEED WITH IT
 }
}
```

see here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9VsG/)

Comment: @joseph - so you want to spoon feed him...?? let him figure out from this example.

Comment: This example does not help the OP in any way. They are not using jQuery, and have no access to its API.

Comment: thanks but i change your code to this http://jsfiddle.net/Q9VsG/ but doesn't work ,on line var nodes=.... get error Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: it's `document.getElementsByName()`